# Swapping Two Different Images / Divs On Refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have been doing much research on how to swap two images or div's on refresh.  I found a few sources, but none did what I want them to do. Here is how I want mine to work:

I have two divs with images in them. One div above the other. The top div will display one image, the bottom div will display a different image. I would like it so every time you refresh or re visit the page, the images or divs switch, whichever one makes more sense.

Here is my simple CSS coding for the ads (which are in my sidebar):

```
#sidebar {float:left; width:300px; min-height:400px; }

#sidebarhomenewsad1 { width:290px; height:580px; margin-bottom:10px; }

#sidebarhomenewsad2 { width:290px; height:580px; margin-bottom:10px; }
```

I made both divs the exact same, just different names because I didn't know if the image swap on refresh would require two different divs or not.

To recap, I would like two different images (one below, one above) to switch / swap with each other when a page is refreshed / re visited.

Any help would be appreciated so so much! :)

Comment: you would have to store what image the visitor saw the first time to be sure they got the other image the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using cookies. On first visit, if cookie ('upper_div_num' for example) is not set, you should show 1st div as upper, and set cookie value to 1. Next time, you should check 'upper_div_num' cookie, and set it to 2 if it's 1, and set it to 1 if it's 2 or not set. PHP or Javascript code should check this cookie value and position divs accordingly.

Comment: Thanks man.  I don't really know how to apply these theories / code structures to paper. I'm not too great with PHP or JS. If you could find the kindness in your heart to come up with some sort of coding that does what I said in the OP, that would be great!! Unfortunately the guys first answer didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Uses [jQuery.cookie()](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

## HTML

```
<img class="a" src="http://i.imgur.com/dCabSb.jpg" />
<img class="b" src="http://i.imgur.com/ZUTsGb.jpg" />​
```

## JS

```
if (!$.cookie('currentImage')) {
    $.cookie('currentImage', '1')
} else {
    if ($.cookie('currentImage') == '1') {

        tmp = $('.a').attr('src');
        $('.a').attr('src', $('.b').attr('src'));
        $('.b').attr('src', tmp);

        $.cookie('currentImage', '2')
    } else {
        $.cookie('currentImage', '1')
    }
}​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mrYaA/

Comment: In your fiddle, the images don't switch on refresh.  I also tried using your codes in my own site and the images still did not switch. :( I tested this on google chrome and mozilla firefox.

Comment: did you keep pressing the Run button?

Comment: Yes, image a remains on the left and image b stays on the right.  They're not switching. :(

Comment: Maybe I have a newer version of Google Chrome than you, what version do you have?